# How to implement a CSS blur within background shorthand?

Tags: html, css, background, blur, shorthand

The goal is to blur the background without blurring all of the other elements above it.

The method of using separate divs for background and content and relying on z-indexes has proven a little inflexible for me, so I want to know if it is possible to implement the CSS blur filter in the background **shorthand** syntax (since "background-filter: blur(5px)" is not valid CSS) which will only apply it to the background.

[Tesla](https://auth.tesla.com/login) did this quite well with shorthand notation, but they used a transparent/black gradient whereas I want to use a blur. Here's some simplified code that I've tried that's based off of the Tesla login page:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="the-CSS-Written-Below">
    </head>
    <body class="background-image">
        <div style="background-color: yellow">
            <p>Some text that shouldn't be blurred!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.background-image{
    background: radial-gradient(transparent, hsl(0, 0%, 2%)), gray url(http://leecamp.net/wp-content/uploads/kitten-3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0L4v34mv/3/) so you can see what it looks like.

Then when I try to change that shorthand filter from radial-gradient to blur, it stops working:

**CSS:**

```
.background-image{
    background: blur(5px), gray url(http://leecamp.net/wp-content/uploads/kitten-3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

I'm not sure if the blur syntax here just isn't right/it needs to be different for shorthand, or maybe this is the completely wrong way of going about this. Is it even possible to blur in shorthand like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `blur` is not a value of the `background` property but rather of `filter`.  According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background#Values):

> The **background** CSS property is a shorthand for setting the individual background values in a single place in the style sheet. background can be used to set the values for one or more of: <background-clip>, <background-color>, <background-image>, <background-origin>, <background-position>, <background-repeat>, <background-size>, and <background-attachment>.

Tesla can use a `background-gradient` because The `background-image` property [can have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image#Formal_syntax) as it's values:

> <bg-image>#
>   where <bg-image> = none | <image>
>   where <image> = <url> | <image()> | <image-set()> | <element()> | <cross-fade()> | <gradient>

To accomplish what you want, it will take 2 divs, something like this:

```css
.background-image {
    background: gray url(http://leecamp.net/wp-content/uploads/kitten-3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:0;
    filter:blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow;position:relative;">
        <p>Some text that shouldn't be blurred!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note that you will have to add a `position:relative` to your other div so that it appears above the background-image div.

I have used the CSS3 `vw` (view-width) and `vh` (view-height) to force the width and height of the `background-image` div, but you could use `%` instead.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the case... but how does this explain radial-gradient (a property of filter, right?) working in the shorthand notation (see the fiddle in the original post)?

Comment: That is true, it will work with `radial-gradient` but only because that is a valid value for the background-image property.  I'm not sure if that makes sense to you?  I'll edit my answer to try to make that more clear.

Comment: Yes, I see now. That's unfortunate that blur doesn't fit into that category. But, we work with what we have. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear.  And yes, I agree: a `background-blur` or even better a `background-filter` would be a really nice addition to the `background-*` properties.